# Formula used by Weka for Standardization of data

Tags: excel, weka

I am trying to standardize a dataset in Weka. I was able too use to standardize function however the results which I have found using Excel and using Weka were little different.

```
Following are the screenshots:
```

**Initial Data**

[image]

**Standardized data given by Weka**

[image]

**Manual Excel results**

[image]

**Formula Used for calculating manual results:**

```
z = (x-mean)/SD

z = Std value
x = value to be standardized
mean = mean of dataset
SD = standard deviation
```

**I would like to know the formula which Weka uses to calculate the standardized value.**

Any help is appreciated!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

To get the formula that weka usage you need to go through the source code that weka provides.

chekc the souece here @  [GC: Standardize - weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize (.java) - GrepCode Class Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Standardize.java?av=f)

You may be able to get the formula you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I checked using Python and NumPy to do the standardization procedure. Weka (v3.6.12) uses indeed

```
z = (x - mean) / std
```

where `std` is the standard deviation. Be sure that your `SD` corresponds indeed the standard deviations (and not the variances, for instance).